# How do I use postman when I am using sign-in with google for authentication in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am making a spring-boot application. In the app, I need to perform sign-in with Google. To do that, I am using oauth2. It's working when I request a hello world api from the web browser. But how do I set-up post man so that I can make api calls from it?

###### Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();

        return httpSecurity.build();

    }

}
```

###### Test Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Hellooo", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

###### application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            clientId: 193483047691-jumfh7674bg1cjmqgfe3v3qfm827cjpt.apps.googleusercontent.com
            clientSecret: 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
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ZoomOptimize
    username: root
    password: aabbffaabb
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true

server:
  port: 8081
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `oauth2Login` (and defined the required client configuration for OAuth2 login to work). For this reason, **your requests are secured with sessions, not Bearer access tokens** => you have to send a valid session cookie with your requests for it to be authorized.

You might go through the OAuth2 login process using your browser as normal and use the Postman interceptor to capture the session cookies. Sample tutorial [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNDSEZF5IpA).

But, if you are using Postman, you are probably writing a REST API. As you are using OAuth2 for security, this API would probably better be configured as an OAuth2 resource server rather than an OAuth2 client. See [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for some OAuth2 background and the various configuration options.

Comment: Wow! that's helpful, thank you. I'll look into the resources you provided. I was just wondering if I wanted to do authentication using Gmail and also make rest APIs that my frontend will call, would that be possible?

Comment: You cannot use Google authorization server for your own resource servers (at least not easily and efficiently). The best option is to use another authorization server with identity federation (aka "Login With..."), there are plenty of OpenID Providers which do it either "from the shelf" (like Keycloak), in the cloud (Auth0, Cognito, ...) or "do it yourself" (Spring Authorization-Server). Again, refer to my tutorials for samples.